# how to I build a NAPTR record in google cloud dns?

Tags: google-cloud-dns

I can't seem to get the syntax down.  I'm putting this on the bare domain and setting the NAPTR data to
10 10 "s" "sip+D2U" "" _sip._udp.mydomain.com
and it says invalid.

Answer (score 2):

The last part of the NAPTR record is a fully qualified domain name, which needs to be terminated with a trailing `.`—so if you try this, it should work:

```
10 10 "S" "SIP+D2U" "" _sip._udp.mydomain.com.
```